# Forward a Copy of Http Requests to another system

Tags: .net, wcf, http, iis

I have a WCF service deployed on production. I'm looking for a tool to forward a 'Copy' of all the messages received by that service to a development server. I need this to debug the requests in my IDE on the Dev box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the source code to the WCF service?  If so, would you be able to modify it and redeploy it with a copy of the communications sent elsewhere?

Otherwise, you could try writing a proxy to intercept the messages, and then forward them on to the existing service and to your dev box.

Also, you might look into ethereal and fiddler for looking at actual network traffic.

Comment: yes I've source code for the WCF service. but I don't want to modify the code. just looking for a tool to intercept and redirect a copy of the messages.